# What is wrong with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

My Visual Studio recently started doing some very strange things. Here are some screenshots (some text is cut from the first screenshot, it is for privacy):

[The Solution Explorer doing weird things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RSgC.png)

[Entire program messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60Vx1.png)

Also, tabs and other controls in Visual Studio sometimes disappears when I move over them, and then they take a little while to come back. Should I reinstall VS (Visual Studio)? Is my installation damaged? Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might start by removing the [ancient adware/spyware](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BonziBuddy) from your system...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that your computer doesn't have the capacity to run VS...

Just restart VS (via task manager if it isn't responding), if problem persists try restarting your computer. If this still doesn't fix it reinstall VS. If you do decide to reinstall, make sure you fully uninstall first otherwise reinstalling would be pointless.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! VS was working fine earlier. I have restarted it and the computer. Still no luck.